# Java reflective assignment of field to null resulting in an IllegaArgumentException

Tags: java, reflection, illegalargumentexception

I've got a deep recursive, reflective method that's purpose is to null out any values in the payload that shouldn't be returned to the caller.  This set of code

```
if (function.apply(attribute)) {
      field.setAccessible(true);
      if (!field.getType().isPrimitive()) {
        log.info("field to be set to null = " + field.getType().getName());
        field.set(object, null);
      }
```

is called repeatedly.  When it hits a particular field, I get the error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field edu.psu.swe.aed.extensions.data.Citizenship.citizenshipCountry to edu.psu.swe.aed.extensions.PersonBioExtension
```

Some of the output from the logging statement to show that it's working up to that point looks like this

```
16:26:35,906 INFO  [edu.psu.swe.scim.server.utility.AttributeUtil] (default task-35) field to be set to null = java.lang.String
16:26:35,906 INFO  [edu.psu.swe.scim.server.utility.AttributeUtil] (default task-35) field to be set to null = edu.psu.iam.services.soap.endpoint.DocumentType
16:26:35,906 INFO  [edu.psu.swe.scim.server.utility.AttributeUtil] (default task-35) field to be set to null = java.util.List
16:26:35,906 INFO  [edu.psu.swe.scim.server.utility.AttributeUtil] (default task-35) field to be set to null = java.util.List
16:26:35,906 INFO  [edu.psu.swe.scim.server.utility.AttributeUtil] (default task-35) field to be set to null = java.lang.String
```

All I can guess is that I've somehow mangled the call stack or the memory model, but I have no idea how to trouble shoot that.  I've completely wiped everything in my target directory to make sure I didn't have a sticky class file, but no luck.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this would happen, or advice on how to continue the troubleshooting?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your exception have line numbers?  Is it really throwing an exception at `field.set(object, null);`? Or maybe another line where you set something to an instance of PersonBioExtension.

Comment: Yes there are line numbers, but in the step ordering recursion I was doing  I munged the memory as described in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  The way I was walking the Object matrix I was nulling a List that contained the Objects then trying to walk the individual object values.  There was enough residual memory footprint that almost looked like it was going to work.  I know the problem, could be fun figuring out the solution...

Comment: Then please select an answer, and check it to mark your question anwered.

Answer (score 2):

Its obvious, why are you setting null value to non string primitive.

To solve this try:
 1. Display type of element along with its current value in log
 2. Check the type of the element giving error
 3. Once tested conditionally set the default value to the element (0,null etc...)

The element above seems to be enum so that needs to be handled is different way as well.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're suggesting.  Null can be assigned to any non-primitive, regardless of whether done reflectively or directly.  The only thing you cannot assign null to is a primitive value.